# Viewing Mahout kmeans cluster points when input is in csv format

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mahout

Hi I am trying to run mahout kmeans clustering with simple iris data set . I have used the following code to convert csv to mahout input

https://github.com/josephmisiti/hadoop-examples/blob/master/mahout/clustering/CSVToMahout.java

The code runs successfully on feeding the output to kmeans . The mahout accepts the code and executes providing the output .

Now the problem is making it back to human readable format .

```
     Configuration config = new Configuration();
        Path path = new Path(args[0]);
        SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(FileSystem.get(config), path, config);
        DenseVector dv = new DenseVector();

        WritableComparable key = (WritableComparable) reader.getKeyClass().newInstance();

        Writable value = (Writable) reader.getValueClass().newInstance();
        long position = reader.getPosition();
        DataOutput out = null;
        //Cluster cl= new Cluster();

        while(reader.next(key,value))
        {

               System.out.println("Key is: "+key +" value is: "+value+"\n");
                //System.out.println(out.toString());
        }
```

The output was something like this

Key is: 0 value is: org.apache.mahout.clustering.iterator.ClusterWritable@47b8b32b

Key is: 1 value is: org.apache.mahout.clustering.iterator.ClusterWritable@47b8b32b

Key is: 2 value is: org.apache.mahout.clustering.iterator.ClusterWritable@47b8b32b

thanks in advance

Comment: that is the default behaviour of toString method - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html?is-external=true#toString()

Comment: Thanks for your response but I need to see the text not the class name

Comment: you need to know which method/property in Writable holds the value you need to see. just use that method/property in sysout - like value.someMothod() instead of value